On a fresh machine, which should come first the syncing of dotfiles or installation of their libraries?
This is a bit of a newbie question but I'm only starting out my journey with dotfiles!
Suppose I have a fresh machine and I want to sync my existing dotfiles/settings from some repo.
A dotfile may or may not have originated from a library which also has to be installed via some operation such as apt install or curl (e.g .gitconfig comes from git).
This being said, which should I install first:

First the associated applications/libraries, and then sync the dotfiles from my repo? If I do this would I be able to overwrite the existing dotfiles that would have been added by installing said applications?

On the other way hand, one can also first sync the dotfiles from my repo and then install the libraries. However, wouldn't this be overwrite the dotfiles you had synced with the default dotfiles added by installing said libraries?



You seem to have answered your own question.  Can you think of any reason to prefer the second option (“first sync the dotfiles from my repo and then install the libraries”)?

Installing packages in most (if not all) distributions, particularly in Debian and its derivatives, does not touch files in users’ home directories. So installing a package won’t overwrite any dotfiles.
In most cases, that’s also true of software installed without using packages.
Some programs will write default dotfiles if you run them without one in place; but obviously for dotfiles to be useful, they won’t overwrite them if they find dotfiles already present (except perhaps when upgrading, and then they should preserve the settings from the existing dotfiles).
So your first scenario shouldn’t be a problem, unless you use the software before syncing your dotfiles. The second scenario shouldn’t be a problem either.
